DAX query: calculating incremental growth of a value by date
Hi Hoping someone can help me out with this Dax query to create a new column of calculated values in an existing table. I'm trying to add a new column that for each row shows the incremental growth in usage over time for each unique combination of CustomerName and ProductName.



CustomerName
ProductName
Usage
Date




CustomerA
service A
2570
2023-06-01


CustomerA
service A
2539
2023-07-01


CustomerA
service A
2579
2023-08-01


CustomerA
service A
2581
2023-09-01


CustomerB
Service B
153
2023-06-01


CustomerB
Service B
406
2023-07-01


CustomerB
Service B
603
2023-08-01


CustomerB
Service C
15
2023-06-01


CustomerB
Service C
16
2023-07-01


CustomerB
Service C
13
2023-08-01



I've tried the following Dax query, but it's not properly calculating the growth.
Calc_IncGrowthOverTime = 
VAR CurrentCustName = [CustomerName]
VAR CurrentWorkLoad = [WorkloadName]
VAR EarliestDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Table1'[Date]), ALL('Table1'), 'Table1'[CustomerName] = CurrentCustName, 'Table1'[WorkloadName] = CurrentWorkLoad)
VAR SoYValue = CALCULATE(MIN('Table1'[Usage]), 'Table1'[Date] = EarliestDate, 'Table1'[CustomerName] = CurrentCustName, 'Table1'[WorkloadName] = CurrentWorkLoad)
RETURN
[Usage] - SoYValue

For rows that aren't the earliest date for that combination of CustomerName and ProductName it's caculating SoYValue as zero so isn't properly calculating the growth.
What I'd like it to return is this...


Can you paste your sample data as copiable text?

updated in main above post. thnx

Can you explain the logic behind your Calc_IncGrowthOverTime ?

Growth = 
VAR x = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[CustomerName], 'Table'[ProductName]))
VAR y = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Usage]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[CustomerName], 'Table'[ProductName]), 'Table'[Date] = x)
RETURN 'Table'[Usage] - y


